# pulseaudio-equalizer's qpaeq launches but doesn't register in pavucontrol, with upgrade to mantic

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I've been using the pulseaudio-equalizer package, specifically its binary qpaeq, to equalize my computer speakers. While I was still on jammy/kinetic it was working. I updated to mantic and it stopped working, in a way that resists troubleshooting.

qpaeq launches normally, and still has the preset I made for it. It has one option in the sink menu, `alsa_output.pci-0000_03_00.6.HiFi__hw_Generic_1__sink.equalizer`. To my memory this hasn't changed.

But as of mantic, when I run qpaeq, a corresponding panel no longer appears as an output option in pavucontrol's Output Devices tab, which means it can't be used. I've confirmed it isn't working invisibly by testing the preamp slider, which from experience when taken to zero mutes the audio it's equalizing. No dice.

Oddly, when I try to unload and reload its modules, pactl claims they're not found:

```
kmfahey@madeline:~:1:$ pactl unload-module module-equalizer-sink; pactl unload-module module-dbus-protocol; pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink; pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol
Failed to unload module: Module module-equalizer-sink not loaded
Failed to unload module: Module module-dbus-protocol not loaded
Failure: No such entity
Failure: No such entity
```

Despite this, I've confirmed the matching module files are present in `/usr/lib/pulse-16.1+dfsg1/modules/` (and v.16.1 is the running pulseaudio version). The directives to load those 2 modules are present in its /etc/pulse/default.pa config file. When I --kill and then --start pulseaudio, of those modules pulseaudio prints this in /var/log/syslog:

```
2023-10-15T13:15:36.516301-07:00 madeline pulseaudio[194451]: module-equalizer-sink is currently unsupported, and can sometimes cause PulseAudio crashes, increased latency or audible artifacts.
2023-10-15T13:15:36.539580-07:00 madeline pulseaudio[194451]: Module "module-dbus-protocol" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.
```

That first line may seem significant, but I looked back in the logs pre-mantic-upgrade and it was saying the same thing; so up til mantic any such unsupportedness wasn't stopping me from using it the way I'm stopped now.

I've tried downgrading pulseaudio, pulseaudio-equalizer, pulseaudio-module-bluetooth, pulseaudio-utils, libpulse-mainloop-glib0, libpulse0, and libpulsedsp back to jammy, which *really should* clear this up. (That's pulseaudio v.15.99 if it matters.) But the same invisibility of qpaeq to pavucontrol persists, likewise the "No such entity" errors, and the same lines in syslog.

So, I'm out of ideas. Can anyone advise me on how to get qpaeq to show up in pavucontrol's Output Devices tab again?